# How to use a map with *args to unpack a tuple in a python function call

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, multiprocessing

I am currently doing a merge over a set of variables that I'd like to parallelize.  My code looks something like this:

```
mergelist = [
  ('leftfile1', 'rightfile1', 'leftvarname1', 'outputname1'),
  ('leftfile1', 'rightfile1', 'leftvarname2', 'outputname2')
  ('leftfile2', 'rightfile2', 'leftvarname3', 'outputname3')
]

def merger(leftfile,rightfile,leftvarname,outvarname):
   do_the_merge

for m in mergelist:
     merger(*m)
```

Ordinarily, to speed up long loops, I would replace the for m in mergelist with something like....

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(8)
p.map(merger(m), mergelist)
p.close()
```

But since I'm using the star to unpack the tuple, it's not clear to me how to map this correctly.  How do I get the `*m`?

Comment: The existence of `itertools.starmap` seems to imply that a standard `map` can't easily be coerced to do this. You can, of course, create a wrapper function that forwards to the actual implementation with the sole argument unpacked.

Comment: How are you defining `merger`? You can't specify string literals as formal parameter names in a function definition.

Comment: Thanks chepner, I corrected that; careless pseudocoding.  I need a better pseudocode interpreter.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the tuple in your merge function:

```
def merger(args):
    if len(args) != 4:
         # error
    leftfile,rightfile,leftvarname,outvarname = args
    do_the_merge
```

The other option is to unpack in the argument list:

```
def merger( (leftfile,rightfile,leftvarname,outvarname) ):
    do_the_merge
```

Edit: to address the OP concerns:

```
def merger((l,r,v,o)):
    return l+r

for m in mergelist:
         print merger(m)
```

returns

```
leftfile1rightfile1
leftfile1rightfile1
leftfile2rightfile2
```

Comment: i didn't know you could do that (unpack in the argument list). very cool.

Comment: Unpacking in the argument list does not seem to work.  It's rejecting my iterable.

Answer (score 4):

Use `lambda`:

```
with Pool(8) as p:
    p.map(lambda m:merger(*m), mergelist)
```

Comment: same idea, but simpler & less typing. a much better solution.

Comment: I slightly redact my love of lambda.  I'm pretty sure this can't be distributed because lambdas can't be pickled: PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution IMHO is to change the merger function, or add a wrapper:

```
def merger(leftfile,rightfile,'leftvarname','outvarname'):
    do_the_merge

def merger_wrapper(wrapper_tuple):
    merger(*wrapper_tuple)

p.map(merger_wrapper, mergelist)
```

I see @delnan actually also put this solution in the comments.

To add a little value to this :) You could also wrap it like this:

```
from functools import partial
def unpack_wrapper(f):
    def unpack(arg):
        return f(*arg)
    return unpack
```

This should let you simplify this to

```
p.map(unpack_wrapper(merger), mergelist)
```

Comment: This seems to produce errors about being unable to pickle the function.

Comment: interesting... while investigating, i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287455/how-do-i-avoid-this-pickling-error-and-what-is-the-best-way-to-parallelize-this and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310536/adding-state-to-a-function-which-gets-called-via-pool-map-how-to-avoid-pickli . maybe they will help?